# Can I add two classes to an element in html in other places?

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm write template (in particular, pagination) for Flask, but dont know, how to safe class "page-item" and give class "disabled"

```
<li class="page-item"
{% if pages.has_prev %}
     class="disabled"
{% endif %}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple classes, but you can't have multiple `class` attributes. They all have to be in the same attribute.

Put the `if` inside the `class` attribute.

```
<li class="page-item {% if pages.has_prev %} disabled {% endif %}" >
```